# Find descendants of an org-mode heading with a certain name?

Tags: org-mode

I saw the `org-ql` package quite recently and was sort of excited that it might be able to [jquery](https://jquery.com/) / [xpath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath) style querying. But having a look at [org-ql](https://github.com/alphapapa/org-ql) I could not quickly find a way of doing this with org-ql?

Is it possible to *programmatically* find the descendants of a heading with a certain name? E.g. if `point` is at a certain heading, how do I find the position of a heading which is a descendant of the first heading and has this name?  What about if I just want to search the children?

## Case 1

```
* Other
* Start <- cursor is here
** Child
*** descendant I want
```

I want a function (preferably one in a library)

```
(find-org-descendant "descendant I want")
```

That will return the position of this descendant

## Case 2

Find *children* rather than descendants.

```
(find-org-child "Child")
```

Comment: I made some edits guessing at what you meant, but please review and make sure that I have not distorted what you meant. Can you also expand the last question ("What about the children?") - I don't know what you mean.

Comment: I've expanded a little. I wanted the position/mark rather than a path - mostly because I don't immediately know how to navigate org trees using paths. Regarding children - I meant how do I search children rather than descendants. I've made this clear and add some case studies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if a library that does exactly this exists already, but you can easily implement such functionalities using the [org-element-api](https://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-element-api.html).

Don't forget to study the API's function docstrings, and read the initial comment in `org-element.el`.

Then your functions could be implemented e.g. as follows:

```lisp
;; it seems that we do not get contents when using the local parse
;; functions `org-element-at-point' or
;; `org-element-context'. Therefore we narrow to the `headline'
;; element and use `(org-element-parse-buffer)'
(defun find-org-descendant (regexp)
  (let ((descendant (org-element-map
                        (save-excursion
                          (save-restriction
                            ;; first walk up to top level
                            (while (/= (org-current-level) 1)
                              (org-up-heading-all 1))
                            (org-narrow-to-element)
                            (org-element-parse-buffer)))
                        'headline
                      (lambda (h) ; filter out headline
                        (when (string-match-p regexp (org-element-property :raw-value h))
                          h))
                      nil t))) ; look up the meaning of these args in docstring
    (org-element-property :begin descendant))) ; now get the position

(defun find-org-child (regexp)
  (let ((child (org-element-map
                   (save-excursion
                     (save-restriction
                       (while (/= (org-current-level) 1)
                         (org-up-heading-all 1))
                       (org-narrow-to-element)
                       (org-element-contents
                        (car
                         (org-element-contents
                          (org-element-parse-buffer))))))
                   'headline
                 ;; (apply-partially #'org-element-property :raw-value)
                 (lambda (h)
                   (when (string-match-p "child" (org-element-property :raw-value h))
                     h))
                 nil t 'headline)))
    (org-element-property :begin child)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Obviously this is very useful... a nice third party library would be great it is existed...

Answer (score 1):

This came up again. I worked out how to create a predicate for this in [org-ql](https://github.com/alphapapa/org-ql).

The following finds all headings under the current heading.

```
(org-ql-defpred my-org-ql-at (point)
  "Search for entries precislely at point"
  :body (progn (message "point" point) (= (point) point)) )

(org-ql-query :select '(point) :from (current-buffer) :where `(ancestors (my-org-ql-at ,(save-excursion (org-back-to-heading) (point)))))
```